# Runnable nullpointerexception when checking with ToggleButton

Tags: android, user-interface, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, togglebutton

I have a `ToggleButton` that is basically determining if a `Runnable` should or should not do something.

Both of these are inside of a `Fragment`, and the `ToggleButton` is instantiated within the rootView of the `Fragment`.

The `Fragment` also contains a method `updateGraphUI` that is called from the `MainActivity`'s `onResume`.

Here is some code examples of `updateGraphUI`:

```
public void updateGraphUI() {

        mTimer2 = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                globalData
                        .setGraph2LastXValue(globalData.getGraph2LastXValue() + 1d);
                globalData.getGraphViewSeries().appendData(
                        new GraphViewData(globalData.getGraph2LastXValue(),
                                getRandom()), true, 300);
                mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);

            }
        };
        mHandler.postDelayed(mTimer2, 100);
    }
```

Now, if I change the code to be like this:

```
public void updateGraphUI() {

        mTimer2 = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(myToggleButton.isChecked()){
                globalData
                        .setGraph2LastXValue(globalData.getGraph2LastXValue() + 1d);
                globalData.getGraphViewSeries().appendData(
                        new GraphViewData(globalData.getGraph2LastXValue(),
                                getRandom()), true, 300);
    }
                mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);

            }
        };
        mHandler.postDelayed(mTimer2, 100);
    }
```

I get a `nullpointerexception` that points to the `if(myToggle.isChecked())` line.

I instantiate the `ToggleButton myToggleButton` in my `Fragment`'s `onCreateView` and assign it using `rootView.findViewById(R.id.myToggleButton);`

Anyone got any ideas on this?

EDIT:

I receive the same errors if I used `isActivated`.

EDIT 2:

Fragment implementation:

```
public class myFragment extends Fragment {

ToggleButton myToggleButton;

static Fragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
    Fragment fragment = new fragment_graphpage();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("0", sectionNumber);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_graphpage_layout,
            container, false);
    myToggleButton = (ToggleButton) rootView
            .findViewById(R.id.realtimetoggle);


    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Try commenting on why you want to close this instead of just downvoting maybe? I did my search on this and couldn't find any specific reason why this error was being called... I instantiate everything correctly as far as I know.

Comment: There is *exactly* one cause of an NPE; the thing you are trying to use is `null`. If what you post is correct, then `myToggle` is `null`. And without anything else, that's all we can tell you.

Comment: Where are you instantiating `myToggle`?

Comment: @Blaine within my OnCreateView I will post the code.

Comment: Is all this code in the same class?

Comment: @Blaine yes it's a Fragment that is used by my MainActivity; which uses the generic Android app starting code.

Comment: Can I not directly access `ToggleButton.isChecked` in a `Fragment` class' methods? Perhaps the only way to access the `isChecked` is to have a listener instead and have that listener change a boolean?

Comment: Going through and just setting a `boolean` with the `onCheckedChangedListener` then calling the `updateUI` method based on that worked fine.

Comment: Though I am not sure why straight checking the `isChecked` method of the `ToggleButton` or the `isActivated` both returned null.